# Can't compile LibSerial on OS X

Tags: c++, macos, libserial

I am working an project that use Arduino and serial port communication. But I've switch my laptop from Win to Macbook Pro and I have to find an alternative for serial communication. Because I use c++ and after some research I decided to use LibSerial. Somehow I can't compile it. The step is following :

```
./configure
make
make install
```

At the "make" step, g++ print statements like :

```
PosixSignalDispatcher.cpp:180:19: error: no matching conversion for functional-style cast from 'char *' to 'PosixSignalDispatcher::CannotAttachHandler'
        throw PosixSignalDispatcher::CannotAttachHandler( strerror(errno) ) ;
```

But when I look into source code, the class PosixSignalDispatcher::CannotAttachHandler is well defined. I can't figure which part goes wrong.

Offering some information :
I use OS X Yosemite and the LibSerial's version is 0.6.0rc2

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following line:

`#include <string>`

BTW, I'm on macOS High Sierra.

Comment: Work also with Ventura 13.3.1